# .htaccess Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've a big problem after I add this line into my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/   index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I have error like that:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/media/css/lvnr.min.css".
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/media/js/bootstrap.min.js".
```

I think that the problem is that my htaccess try to redirect all the link media/... to index.php?p=
...

So how to fix it please

Answer (score 2):

As you already assumed, your rule matches your media/...
You probably want your regex to end on $:

```
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/$   index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Edit: Also you might be interested in loading public libraries like boostrap from a CDN for better performance:

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will make sure that the RewriteRule will only trigger if the file does not exist (so the rewriterule will no longer trigger for the css files for example).