# RewriteRule can't read png dynamic image

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mime-types

I've created a RewriteRule to allow a friendly url for signup in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php
```

It works everything fine, although a png image generated by a captcha field dinamically shows a broken link. If i run this script by raw signup.php request it works fine.

The captcha source is something like

```
?___event=getimage&___input=captcha&___image=6S024g%3D%3D%3A1430648449
```

Requesting the script by rewriterule i receive this message:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://mysite.nil/signup?___event=getimage&___input=captcha&___image=6S024g%3D%3D%3A1430648449"

I've tried everything, looked on google and apache logs with no success.

I would appreciate any help who could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your captcha source has no scheme,domain, or resource part: only a query part, the browser will substitute the page location, resulting in a request for  ...`/signup?___event=getimage`...  apache only matches agoinst the resource part, so your pattern can stay the same, but you need to tell apache to match keep the query string after the rewrite by using the `QSA` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php  [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create an different RewriteRule for the captcha?

[.htaccess Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233162/htaccess-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-htm)

Like said here, maybe you can try to end that link with .png?

```
RewriteRule ^signup.png$ signup.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Still not working, i've also tried   RewriteRule ^signup?___event=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&___input=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&___image=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ signup.php?___event=$1&___input=$2&___image=$3